# How to make a dropdownlist disabled depending on second dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am having two dropdownlists and in 1st if I select country another is populated with the corresponding states but I want to grey out the second DDL and display a message like select the state in it. How can I achieve this? I am not using AJAX for this.

Comment: well enable the dropdown only when a value is selected in the first (postback and handle the selectedindex change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just temporary disable it on server side?

```
ddl2.Enabled = false;
```

Or better do like this, on first changed, check the state, if smth is choosen, then enable secondary ddl.

```
ddl1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender....)
{
    if (ddl1.SelectedIndex != 0)
        ddl2.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: How can i display some message in DDL2

Comment: thanks,it is so simple until i know it :)

Comment: yw, it all becomes simple with time.